# create menu filter price product

Tags: views, 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

salute you. I have one problem need your help. I want to create 2 menu list of product categories and product prices. there should be a link between two product categories menu to the product menu to display the products desired by the user. for example i have 2 menu after

categories:

- dell servers
- ibm server
- hp server

  price:
- $ 100 to $ 500
- $ 500 to $ 1000
- $ 1000 to $ 2000

When I click on dell server it will display all the products dell server and when I continued to click $ 100 to $ 500 it will display the products of dell servers have priced 100 $ to 500 $. thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for there is not a menu but faceted search, the best way to do this is to install and configure [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi).